# Why TObject.Free is called before the first line of code of my application is executed?

Tags: delphi, memory, procedure

We are trying to figure out if we have memory leaks in our software. So, I have been using various tools and programs to help me find possible memory leaks. One of the software I used was AQTime. As it came with Delphi XE, it was only a demo. So, I was not really able to get any useful information from it. Then, I decided to use free software, MemProof. So far, it has shown me many issues with our software that requires attention. One of which is an error.

As soon as I start my program through MemProof, it lists 2 errors, which is attempting to destroy non-existent object from the unit file, system.pas. So, when I actually put a break point within TObject.Free procedure, it breaks even before my program started all the way. Stepping through the procedure Free in system.pas, I found out that TIconimage is trying to destroy or free itself. In other word, free procedure is not invoked from within my program prior to actually starting up.

Here is the actual Free procedure:

```
procedure TObject.Free;
begin
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
end;
```

After that observation, I removed the breakpoint and let the program run all the way. My programs main window popped up ready for user input. However, I also found out that TObject.Free procedure is invoked non-stop if any part of my program's WINDOW is displayed on the screen. I don't understand that at all. Why is that? Can anyone explain? How is TForm is related to TObject.Free in any shape or form as the procedure is constantly invoked when the TForm is displayed on the screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you mention AQTime demo I assume you mean Delphi XE rather than Delphi 2010 XE and I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding why `TObject.Free` executes a lot, every single time an object is destroyed, any object, that method will be called.  All classes derive from TObject, it's the common ancestor, so almost any action in a Delphi program involves large numbers of object create/destroy pairs and consequently will hit `TObject.Free`.

Regarding detection of memory leaks, you have all you need built in to Delphi to solve this.  The FastMM memory manager can be run in "report memory leaks" mode and it will give you loads of diagnostics of any memory that you leak.

Consider the following trivial program:

```
program Leaker;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  TObject.Create;
end.
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

You just need to set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` to True somewhere in your app (the start of the .dpr file is as good a place as any).

If you wish to receive more information in the report then you can download the [full version of FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) and configure it to your heart's content.

Then you get output like this:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 84

This block was allocated by thread 0x1304, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
40455E [System][System.@GetMem]
405A2F [System][System.TObject.NewInstance]
40602E [System][System.@ClassCreate]
4474C2 [Classes][Classes.TStringList.Create]
C275A3 [Main.pas][Main][Main.TMainForm.CreateAuxiliaryForms][997]
C84C8A [OrcaFlex.dpr][OrcaFlex][OrcaFlex.OrcaFlex][351]
75E633CA [BaseThreadInitThunk]
77519ED2 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]
77519EA5 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TStringList
```

It's truly wonderful. It tells me that the leaking memory was allocated in Main.pas line 997, and that's precisely where I put my intentional leak!

Comment: Remember Project options->Linker->Map File->Detailed

Comment: @David Heffernan - I have used FastMM before in my program to test for leaks and For some reason, I find it very confusing. In other ward it doesn't seem to be straight forward. When you set ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown to true, all you get to see is list of leaks and its corresponding objects in the program only when you shutdown your program. You can tell if they are real leaks or legitmate one. I could download full FastMM and tweak the settings, which I have done also, but in fact it is more confusing. I need to be able to see live counts of objects being created and destroyed.

Comment: @user What's the confusion? It gives you a list of leaks. You shouldn't have any! And what is a legitimate leak? If you really want to intentionally leak something there is a facility for you to mark a block as such.

Comment: I meant to say, "You CAN'T tell if they are real leaks or legitimate one."

Comment: @user You have to mark the legitimate ones as such and then any that are reported are real leaks. There is seldom need for legitimate leaks so I suspect you have a real problem and FastMM will help you solve it.

Comment: @David So, say you create an object and put it in a TList. This object you created must be kept in the memory as long as your program runs. Only when you shut it down, the object is destroyed. Would you consider that to be a memory leak? I have several TList and loaded with objects that must stay alive in the memory for as long as my program runs or lives. So, when I shutdown my program, I get a FastMM message box with list of leaks. A lot of what it reports as leaks I see are objects created by my program that are supposed to be kept in the memory for all time unless the program is shutdown.

Comment: @user if you don't redesign that you'll never be able to tell the difference between real leaks and false positives. There's invariably a way to write the code so that the memory is deallocated at shutdown. You are now reaping the results of that design decision. You now will find it practically impossible to debug the problem until deal with this design flaw.

Comment: @David I reviewed my source files after reading your comment just to make sure the objects are released or freed and they are. They are all destroyed when the TForms are destroyed within FormDestroy Events, unless FastMM is not letting my program shutdown all the way before it displays the leak message box. Thus, it sees all the objeccts not freed as leaks. This program has run flawlessly under Windows 98, 2000 and XP. Now, it is having problems.

Comment: @user FastMM is installed before the first heap allocation and removed after the last heap allocation. It's detection of leaks works.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, `TApplication` has an `Icon` property which you can f.i. assign in the application settings in project options. This property is reflected with an `FIcon` field of TApplication which is created in the constructor of the `Application` object. `TIcon` has a `TIconImage` field representing the actual image which gets created in its constructor. When the Application object loads and assigns the icon from the project resource file, this initial 'TIconImage' has to be freed in order to prevent a leak. All this happens even before `Application.Initialize` is called in the project source, because the Application object is constructed from the initialization section of 'controls.pas'.

Lots of things are happening when an application is launching or running. When launching, the streaming mechanism creates objects (resource streams, readers, class finders, component lists ..) and then frees them. Even a blank VCL form (with no controls on it) when running, creates a list each time it gets activated to find a control to put the focus on, and then frees this list. With complex GUI applications, a variety of graphics objects can be created and freed even if you hover the mouse on something. Or the alignment/arrangement code can create/free objects even if you press your mouse on to something.

To debug leaks you can take the course outlined by [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331783/memproof-and-system-pas/5332020#5332020), or when using a 3rd party product concentrate on what it says leaked, not on every object which gets created/freed. :)

Comment: Interesting. I always thought that only after your program is started everything else is invoked or initiated. However, I did notice that when Memproof displayed errors at startup, I was able to break it in the Free procedure and analyze self <> nil if condition and found out that self was set to nil. So, "Nothing" is  trying to free itself. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user - The program is started after CreateProcess is called, that's quite before execution reaches 'begin' in the project source or a form becomes visible... Generally an object does not try to free itself, rather they are freed by whom they're created. Regardless, the nil test is there for the exact reason you have discovered, an object might be constructed or not depending on conditions, with a nil reference it is safe to call free on it... Put a breakpoint in the 'Destroy' line of the 'TObject.Free' in 'system.pas', that's after the nil test, and launch your application in the debugger...

Comment: .. You'll see it will be hit many times. From the call stack, you can determine what is being freed and why..

Answer (score 0):

**TObject.Free** will be called whenever ANY instance of a class in Delphi is **Free**'d.

This includes a whole host of objects that are created and destroyed simply as part of the normal execution of a Delphi program, including in response to events processed automatically by a **TForm** object in response to the messages generated by the system simply to maintain the window object itself in existence in the **Windows** own *Window Manager*.

For example, consider this snipped fragment of code from the **TCustomForm WndProc**:

```
      WM_MEASUREITEM:
      begin
         :
                Canvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
                with Canvas do
                try
                  :
                finally
                  Canvas.Free;
                end;
        :
      end;
```

The key here being that in response to a **WM_MEASUREITEM** message, a custom form (and therefore a standard **TForm** derived class, since this ultimately derives from **TCustomForm**) creates a temporary **TControlCanvas**, which it then **Free**'s when it is finished with it.

This may not necessarily be the source of the **TObject.Free** calls that you are seeing in your particular form's case, it is just an example, but shows how a **TForm** merely existing can result in *other* objects being brought into existence and destroyed in response to automatic, system generated messages.

Comment: I see. That's what I thought. Thanks.